# How to change the legend bar and colors to show each row in Dataframe individually? (Accdg to index_col)

Tags: python, django, charts, plotly, gantt-chart

How can I change the legend bar and colors to show each row in Dataframe individually? My current chart looks like this:

[image: This is a production schedule. Each row in Dataframe is a job.]

The code is below:

```
def chart(task_list, filename):
    fig = ff.create_gantt(task_list, colors='Rainbow', index_col='Resource', show_colorbar=True, group_tasks=True)
    # plot(fig, filename=filename)
    return plot(fig, filename=filename, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
    #print(fig)
```

'**Rainbow**' is a default plotly colorscale. However, it is limited to just two colors if I'm not mistaken.

I just want the chart to have a legend that is similar to this (be it dots or lines, just not a gradient bar like the current Gantt):

[image: This is from the Plotly Gantt Chart documentation.]

Code for this is as follows:

```
df = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2016-01-01', Finish='2016-01-02', Resource='Apple'),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2016-01-02', Finish='2016-01-04', Resource='Grape'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2016-01-02', Finish='2016-01-03', Resource='Banana')]

colors = dict(Apple = 'rgb(220, 0, 0)',
              Grape = 'rgb(170, 14, 200)',
              Banana = (1, 0.9, 0.16))

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', show_colorbar=True)
py.iplot(fig, filename='gantt-dictioanry-colors', world_readable=True)
```

However, when I use the code from the documentation, it only has a limited number of colors, set by the dict **colors**. I want the colors to be able to generate on its own whenever a new row comes in from the Dataframe.

TLDR; need a COLORSCALE that will be able to accommodate increasing numbers of rows in Dataframe and to change the gradient bar to lines/dots/whatever to serve as LEGENDS for each Dataframe row as per the index_col.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Change `Resource` to string before you pass it to `def chart(task_list, filename)`
So that `plot.ly` takes `Resource` as a discrete category instead of a continuous measure.

```
task_list.Resource = task_list.Resource.apply(str)

import random

all_the_colors = list((x,y,z) for x in range(256) for y in range(256) for z in range(256))

colors = [f"rgb({random.choice(all_the_colors)})" for x in df.Resource.unique()]

def chart(task_list, filename):
    fig = ff.create_gantt(task_list, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', show_colorbar=True, group_tasks=True)
    # plot(fig, filename=filename)
    return plot(fig, filename=filename, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
    #print(fig)
```

Comment: Hello! It returns an error similar to one I've had before:

Error. The number of colors in 'colors' must be no less than the number of unique index values in your group column.